# linux + xzcat command

Tags: software-installation, xz

Please advice from where ( which site )  I can download the xzcat Linux command?

I am using linux version 5.4

I tried to download the xzcat from the site:

http://www.filewatcher.com/m/xzcat.2-0.html

but when I run the xzcat on my linux machine I get the following:

```
 /tmp/xzcat  initrd.img | cpio -idm
-bash: /tmp/xzcat: cannot execute binary file
 cpio: premature end of archive
```

I also tried insted the xzcat

```
cpio -id < initrd.img 
cpio: warning: skipped 72460 bytes of junk
cpio: warning: archive header has reverse byte-order
```

Comment: 1. what linux distro are you using?  whatever it is, it probably already has xzcat packaged.  it's almost always better to use the distro packaged version of a program than to download a random binary or compile from source.

Comment: 2. your /tmp is probably mounted 'noexec', meaning you can't execute programs stored on it.

Comment: no my /tmp isnt mounted! ( umount /tmp
umount: /tmp: not mounted )

Comment: sorry but what you mean about "distro packaged version" what I need to do? in order to install the xzcat?

Comment: The "can't execute binary file" is because the binary you downloaded isn't compatible with your system.  For example, trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit system.  The solution is to install the packaged version for your linux distribution.  The exact details on how to do that depend on what distro you are running, and you still haven't answered that question.

Comment: Linux 5.4? Linus has had a productive night, we were still on 3.11 yesterday!

Comment: It also would be good idea to tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xzcat` is usually part of the `xz` package. Install that package using your Linux distribution package management tool (you haven't mentioned *what* Linux distribution you are using - like Debian, RedHat etc.).